# Виртуальное наследование в C++

Tags: c++

Что это такое и зачем это используют в C++?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Виртуальное наследование необходимо в такой ситуации.

```
class A { int a; };
class B: public A {};
class C: public A {};
class D: public B, public C {};
```

В классе `D`, в таком случае, будут два поля с именем `a` и они оба будут принадлежать классу `A`. 
Проблема состоит в определении к какой переменной идет обращение. Для исключения подобной ситуации используют виртуальное наследование. Правильный вид объявления в данном примере будет

```
class A { int a; };
class B: public virtual A {};
class C: public virtual A {};
class D: public B, public C {};
```